# Open a tab and make a POST request to it in a firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

In my addon I have to submit data as urlencoded POST, for now I used a js script to do that (inject a form in the current page and submit it) but I wonder if there is a solution to do that with the Firefox Addon SDK?

I haven't found a clue in the high-level API but I am less familiar with the low-level, is it possible with the 'window/utils' [openDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/window_utils#openDialog%28options%29) method?
There is some args parameter but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks.

EDIT

To be specific I need to mimic the behavior of an html form in a new tab.

Comment: Lots of topics on StackOverflow on this subject in the last copule months. Search for `FormData` and they were also doing some open new tab with data posted in some interesting ways. You can also do it with XHR. It's all in the topics in the firefox-addon tag, awesome topics too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out these two topics: (1) [Replication of Form method with loadOneTab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25009431/replication-of-form-method-with-loadonetab/25020668#25020668) and (2) [Use Blob on firefox add-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19780396/use-blob-on-firefox-add-on/19780896#19780896)

An interesting thing you can do is, XHR request it and with the returned source make it a blob and load load blob in tab:

```
var {Blob, File} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm", {});
var oFileBody = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var oBlob = Blob([oFileBody], { type: "text/html"});
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(oBlob); //returns a string like blob:null/bbe1b94e-0800-4af2-9d9e-df09c0b9cab3 so paste that into your url bar
```

OR just see how @nmaier is posting data to new tab.

OR the messy way, make a data url out of the source code like `data:text/html,**rawr**' and put that in your url bar. i prefer @nmaiers methods

OR again just see how @nmaier is posting data to new tab. (i love his way)

Comment: Thanks, finally I used the answer from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19403213/424072 for the postData and the loadOneTab and moveTabTo methods to open and place the tab.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you did in the end. It helps others who come across the same stuff in the future. And also for my knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add code to my comment, I did this:

```js
const querystring = require('sdk/querystring');
let stringStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
stringStream.data = querystring.stringify(params); // params is a json data

let postData = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/mime-input-stream;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsIMIMEInputStream);
postData.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
postData.addContentLength = true;
postData.setData(stringStream);

var tabBrowser = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator).getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser").gBrowser;
var selectedTabIndex = tabBrowser.tabContainer.selectedIndex;
var newTab = tabBrowser.loadOneTab("https://myurl.com/", {
    inBackground: false,
    postData: postData
});
tabBrowser.moveTabTo(newTab, selectedTabIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/request) to send your data.

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
var latestTweetRequest = Request({
  url: "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=mozhacks&count=1",
  onComplete: function (response) {
    var tweet = response.json[0];
    console.log("User: " + tweet.user.screen_name);
    console.log("Tweet: " + tweet.text);
  }
});
```

Comment: I know that I can use Request to send a request, but I need to display the resulting html to a new tab, so that doesn't work.
To be specific I need to mimic the behavior of an html form.

Comment: @JérémieBertrand So why not send the resulting HTML to the new tab and append it to the document?